# Order complete and complete metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Suppose we have a [complete ordered set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order#Completeness) (i.e. a totally ordered set with the [lub property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least-upper-bound_property)) and the order topology happens to be metrizable.  Does it follow that this space is a [complete metric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space)?

Comment: The order on $(0, 1)$ is complete, but the standard metric on it (which generates the order topology) is not complete.

Comment: Though if you also assume your ordered set have a maximal element and a minimal element, then the order topology is compact, so any metric inducing the topology must be complete.

Comment: Since the order topology of a totally ordered set is [uniformizable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformizable_space), I guess a better question would be to ask if the finest uniform structure compatible with the order topology of a complete totally ordered set is complete.

Comment: @P. P. Tuong: I guess your proposal goes into a completely different direction, since this has (apparently) not very much to do with completeness of the order: for instance $\mathbb Q$ is paracompact, hence it is complete w.r.t. its finest uniformity, whereas $\omega_1$ is complete as an ordered space (in the above sense), but not complete w.r.t. its finest uniformity.

Comment: Taking into account the negative answer of David Gao and following the proposal of P. P. Tuong, we have as a positive result: If the order is complete, then the order topology is locally compact. Hence, if it is metrizable, then there exists a complete metric, which induces the order topology.